# Python Gravity Simulation

Tags: python, scipy, physics, differential-equations

I am trying to write code to simulate the gravity of a plant (earth in this case) orbiting a star (the sun). I am using scipy.integrate.solve_ivp using the boundary conditions to solve the differential equation. The problem is the orbit of the earth is not what I would expect (shown below) and I don't know where I'm going wrong. The initial conditions were obtain from the nasa JPL website. The following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
    
# Constants

G = 6.67408e-08
msun = 1988500e24
m = msun

au = 149597870.700e3 - AU to m
v_factor = 1731460 # As velocities given in AU/day so conversion needed -> m/s

# Position of earth - data from JPL

x_pos = 1.168490293769851E-01*au
y_pos = 9.773086489128535E-01*au
z_pos = -4.581805315603911E-05*au

x_vel = -1.737065829712975E-02*v_factor
y_vel = 1.978209219640221E-03*v_factor
z_vel = 6.491444436868095E-07*v_factor

def f_grav(t, y):
    x1, x2, x3, v1, v2, v3 = y
    dydt = [v1, v2, v3, -x1 * G * m / (x1 ** 2 + x2 ** 2 + x3 ** 2)**(3/2), -x2*G*m/(x1**2+x2**2+x3**2)**(3/2), -x3*G*m/(x1**2+x2**2+x3**2)**(3/2)]
    return dydt

year = 31557600.e0 # seconds in 365.25 days
tEnd = 1.0 * year

domain = (0, tEnd)
init = [x_pos, y_pos, z_pos, x_vel, y_vel, z_vel]
ans = solve_ivp(fun=f_grav, t_span=domain, y0=init)

plt.plot(ans['y'][0], ans['y'][1])
plt.plot([0.],[0.],'o')

plt.show()
```

produces the following graph. However I am unsure why the earth spirals into the sun. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Isn't G typically `6.67408e-11`

Comment: jeez, that's it. Spent far to long trying to figure out what was wrong. Thank you very much

Comment: @PeterK : That is the scalar force. For the vector force you get an additional factor `-x/r`.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? At the moment with the change of G it orbit is correct. Where would I add that?